# Does using display: table delay page rendering like with actual table elements?

Tags: html, css, performance, css-tables

As I remember, besides semantic concerns one disadvantage of styling websites using tables was the page load: the website could only be displayed when the whole table was loaded.

Does the same apply to divs styled as tables, i.e.

```
.container { display: table; }
```

Guess not, because there's no table in the HTML, right?

Comment: In general it won't affect the load time - but use the dev tools such as firebug to inspect the timeline - then you can tell how long parts of the page are taking to load. Normally html elements will be almost instantaneous in modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that.

Comment: You're right, Simon. BOOM, there it is – instantly.

Comment: The problem with _rendering_ large tables is that the content of every single cell must be “evaluated” to see how wide each column has to be made (unless widths are given and table-layout is fixed). I would expect it to perform more or less the same, regardless of whether “actual” table elements are used, or other elements are formatted as table elements via CSS.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to rendering instead of loading. 
Widths are given in percentages (for table and cells). My layout only consists of a few (large) wrapper cells, so this shouldn't be too much of a problem, right?

Comment: @SimonMason, a proper answer would allow this question to be resolved. Comment-answers effectively shut down the SE Q&A routine.